# swift generic func with overlapping type constraints

Tags: swift, generics, type-constraints, generic-function

I have this protocol hierarchy:

```
protocol A {}

protocol B: A {}
```

what will happen if I have the 2 following funcs:

```
func myFunc<T : A where T: B>( object: T){ ... }
func myfunc<T : A>( object: T){ ... }
```

Which function will be executed if I call

```
myFunc( object: myInstance )
```

with `myInstance` conforming to protocol `B`. In this case `myInstance` matches the 2 constraints.

Thanks

Comment: You can try it yourself you know ;)

Comment: Wanted to know what the general rule was.

Comment: I figured as much and was actually in the middle of writing an answer when Daniel swooped in. Although you should note that this question only ever asks for "which function will be executed", not why a given function will be executed. It always helps to be explicit in exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that the compiler tries to select the *most* specific / *most* constrained overload.

For your example above, it would be the first version of `myFunc`